# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: unity3d

Estou com este erro:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object EnemyMovement.Awake () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Enemy/EnemyMovement.cs:13)

Código:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Transform player;

    NavMeshAgent nav;


    void Awake ()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform;

        nav = GetComponent <NavMeshAgent> ();
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        //if(enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0 && playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
        //{
            nav.SetDestination (player.position);
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    nav.enabled = false;
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Consegue provar que a tag é exatamente `Player`, e que ele já está na cena pra conseguir ser acessado pelo método? Porque não tem nada de errado no seu código.

Comment: muito bom. obrigado.